# trudesk ticketing system stoped working suddenly

Tags: node.js, pm2

```
11/23 07:18:15 [3112] - �[32minfo�[39m: trudesk v1.0.2 Copyright (C) 2014-2018 Chris Brame
11/23 07:18:15 [3112] - �[32minfo�[39m:
11/23 07:18:15 [3112] - �[32minfo�[39m: Running in: development
11/23 07:18:15 [3112] - �[32minfo�[39m: Server Time: Fri Nov 23 2018 07:18:15 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
11/23 07:18:16 [3112] - �[32minfo�[39m: Connected to MongoDB
11/23 07:18:19 [3112] - �[32minfo�[39m: TruDesk is now listening on port: 8118
11/23 07:18:19 [3112] - �[32minfo�[39m: SocketServer Running
11/23 07:18:20 [3112] - �[34mdebug�[39m: Checking Default Settings...
11/23 07:18:20 [3112] - �[34mdebug�[39m: Timezone set to America/New_York
TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
at C:\Program Files\iCuboid\trudesk-master\src\settings\defaults.js:109:33
at C:\Program Files\iCuboid\trudesk-master\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4451:16
at model.Query.(anonymous function).call (C:\Program Files\iCuboid\trudesk-master\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:3606:7)
at C:\Program Files\iCuboid\trudesk-master\node_modules\kareem\index.js:315:21
at C:\Program Files\iCuboid\trudesk-master\node_modules\kareem\index.js:135:16
at args.(anonymous function) (C:\USERS\ICUBOID\APPDATA\ROAMING\NPM\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\event-loop-inspector\index.js:138:29)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:112:11)`
```

i am using trudesk node js web application.
its using mongo db as database.i installed in my local its working .but in server on running the app i am getting this error

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue a while ago when I was messing around with the database. I got around it by validating the object that's referenced in src\settings\defaults.js at line 109 (according to the error above and [the github repo at this time](https://github.com/polonel/trudesk/blob/master/src/settings/defaults.js)).

You can see the issue in code, where type._id is referenced. You need to confirm that type is an object and that _id is a string. Starting at line 107:

```
            var defaultTicketType = new SettingsSchema({
                name: 'ticket:type:default',
                value: type._id
            });
```

Change that so validation of the object happens before the object's keys are referenced:

```
            if (typeof type !== 'object' ||  typeof type._id !== 'string' ) return;
            var defaultTicketType = new SettingsSchema({
                name: 'ticket:type:default',
                value: type._id
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (typeof type !== 'object' ||  typeof type._id !== 'string' ) return;
```

Although this is a valid check, the return is not calling the `callback` thus preventing the default script from completing an exiting correctly. Also `_id` may not always read as a string and the `value` is of Mixed type.

```
if (!_.isObject(type) || _.isUndefined(type._id)) return callback('Invalid Type. Skipping.')
```

I've added the above check to the codebase. The reference function is called if it detects the default ticket type setting is not present. This should only occur on the first startup unless manually removing/updating documents from MongoDB.